# can't commit with sublime text git on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: git, sublimetext, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04

When I'm trying to commit my work from inside sublime it gives me the following message:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'my_project_path/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

I checked that but the **index.lock** is not exists at all! and when I commit in terminal everything is good.

any ideas?

Comment: Is there a permission issue? (does sublime text runs with your account?) Removing the file should be enough (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20827294/6309), but in your case, check if there isn't any "git" processes running (ps -ef|grep git)

Comment: honestly, I don't know if it's a permission issue or not.
I used the command as you mentioned: **ps -ef|grep git** and got the following results: **raeef    32550 27757  0 09:19 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto git**
if this is another process, so how to stop it? and why it's not affecting when I commit in the terminal?

Comment: It appears by that output another git process is not running. I believe at this point it is a permissions issue or a problem with the version of Git you are using with Sublime Text.

Comment: my sublime version is **3 build 3065** and tried on **build 3059**, git package is **v2014.07.13.22.18.27** and git version is **2.1.0**

if it's permissions issue, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Does the index.lock file still exist if you go check for it? (If it does, that's indicative of a command having aborted. If it doesn't, two commands might be trying to run simultaneously.)

Comment: have a tried a different git build?

Comment: No, but are you sure that I need different git build while it's 100% working in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded git from **2.1.0** to **1.9.1** and all good now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
rm -f my_project_path/.git/index.lock
```

Sometimes, there is inconsistencies preventing git to release the lock, you also, just in case, should run git consistence checks to make sure your local git repo is consistent:

```
git fsck
```