# This .git/index.lock file automatically gets created and not able to perform push operation

Tags: git, git-push

This `.git/index.lock` file automatically gets created whenever `git add .` command is given in Git bash.

Even after deleting the file manually, and it generates lots of warnings.

How can I resolve this, and use `git push`?

Comment: Please post the command that you executed and any message that git throws.

Comment: [what are lockfiles?](https://fileinfo.com/extension/lock)

Comment: It's normal for Git to create `.git/index.lock`. But normally Git *deletes or renames* the file afterward, to release the lock. This should Just Work and you should not have to delete `.git/index.lock`. If it's not working, you should include additional details about the problem, because we can't *guess* why it's not working. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the local system (OS, server type, disk space, ...), as illustrated in "git `index.lock` File exists when I try to commit, but cannot delete the file".

It can be a process keeping an handle to the lock file, or it can be a permission issue.

So before trying a git push, you must first understand why the `index.lock` file remains.

As I mention in "[if git `index.lock` exist, can I safely delete it, or are more actions needed to verify integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20827294/6309)", a workaround is to delete it manually, before pushing.